# picture-in-picture with parts cut off

Tags: html, css, image

I'm a total newbie. And I ran into this problem. Alas, I did not find a definite answer on the net, so I decided to turn here.
The task is that I need to overlay the pictures on top of each other, so that it looks like in screenshot No. 2, i.e. we have a yellow spot overlay, and a full size image that needs to be cropped.
From what I know, I've tried everything. I ask for help and do not throw tomatoes. Thanks in advance

Example code (html, css):

```
   <p class="card">
       <img class="one" src="/" alt="123">
       <img class="two" src="/" alt="123">
   </p>
```

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
}

.one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 55px;
  z-index: 5;

}

.two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

[image: bad try]
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mask image property to mask like that shape and use position:absolute and do Further

```
 -webkit-mask-image: url(---.png);    //use the image shape to mask
 mask-image: url(---.png);
-webkit-mask-size: 70%;
mask-size: 70%;
-webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
mask-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Sry, I could not find the information I needed, this is the first time I see this property